/mnt/wslg/.X11-unit/X0 Unix Domain Socket Is Missing in WSL Ubuntu on Windows 11
Had X11 working on Windows 11 with WSL, then for reasons not fixed found that X11 is no longer producing working results.
Tried:
C:\Users\Yevgeny S>wsl -e xcalc
and got:
Error: Can't open display: :0
It is believable, according to some W3 resources that WSL on Windows 11 will run without additional X11 Server.
Some sources say that there should be a symlink called /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 to target /mnt/wslg/.X11-unix/X0 and Ubuntu on WSL appears to have it, but the target in /mnt/... is not there.  One source for this is on youtube "(Resolved) WSLg Error: Can't open display: :0 in Windows 11" by Sonoo's KB.
Pretty sure that one of these kits deleted the device during install:
l_HPCKit_p_2023.1.0.46346_offline.sh
l_BaseKit_p_2024.2.1.100_offline.sh
l_AIKit_p_2023.1.0.31760_offline.sh <-- most likely this one
Intel extensions for PyTorch had a long error help threads on GitHub and the closed ones are the ones with successful installs on bear metal.  Maybe I wish to loose these installs.
Any idea on how to get /mnt/wslg/.X11-unix/X0 back?  sudo apt-get reinstall xorg -y did not do it.
Tried to fix it:

Expected to find /mnt/wslg/.X11-unix/X0 on the file system.

Expected the resintall of xorg to succeed in restoring X11 functionality.

$ sudo python3 -c "import socket as s; sock = s.socket(s.AF_UNIX); sock.bind('/mnt/wslg/.X11-unix/X0')" Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system
3.a  Had some success creating the Domain Socket, it did not bring the X11 functionality back up.

Tried reinstalling distro, X11 worked for a few minutes; then did apt-get with a bunch of python3.11-* packages, X11 stopped working.  Did discover that X0 Bound Socket is not so needed though.


Any steps I could take to restore the /mnt/wslg/.X11-unix/X0 Unix Domain Socket properly?  Or what should I do to keep X11 functionality stable?
Thanks.
